# Google api V3 make dropdown select list for places, take value from lat lng from json txt file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make map with google api v3, I make dropdwon select list for places and take value from latitude & longitude

Manually i do this

```
      <option value="-6.9666, 110.4166">title1</option>
```

I have json data  named data.txt, then I want to take value from lat & lng, but the shown one is the title.

```
[
  {
    "title": "title1",
    "lat": -6.984,
    "lng": 110.41
  }
]
```

I try to do this, but it doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('data.txt', function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(i, option){        
            console.log(option.title)
            $('#start').append($('<option/>')
                .attr("value",option.lat,option.lng)
                .text(option.title));
        });
    });
});
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Any error in console/network tab? Does the success callback fired or not?

Comment: there's no error in console/network tab, but the dropdown select list is blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('#start').append($('<option/>')
        .attr("value",option.lat + ", " + option.lng)
        .text(option.title));
```